# How to make attachment control work in Access 2016?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I placed an attachment control on the form in Access 2016, but it doesn't seem to do anything. It shows up as a blank box, and I can't browse any files to attach. The control source is set to a field Attachment which is of Attachment datatype. Please help!

Thanks,
Howard

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue. I created control by dragging from the form design field list.

Comment: I am not using any of the Access provided record controls- such as new record, update record, next record, etc. I am using programmed buttons for record control. I wrote code for new record, update record, delete record, etc.

Comment: Managing records has nothing to do with creating control for the attachment field.

Comment: When I right-click the attachment control, I get a pop-up menu which has an option: "Manage attachments", but it is grayed out.